# use of 'those' for clarity in this context

Tags: pronouns

This is from [a webpage](https://ekja.org/journal/view.php?number=8734).

> All patients successfully underwent ultrasound-guided SCB regardless
> of approach, and there were no complications directly related to the
> technique including pneumothorax **or the use of** local anesthetics.

From what I read on the internet, there are a few categories of complications of SCB.

They include technical complications such as pneumothorax or drug-related complications such as anaphylaxis to local anesthetics.

So I think, for clarity, it is better to rewrite the part in bold as '*or those related to the use of*'.

Am I wrong?

Comment: I'm no medical expert, but the sentence does seem oddly worded to me, since pneumothorax is a problem but 'the use of local anaesthetics' is not.

Comment: @KateBunting Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree it should be changed. As it is written right now, a reader might think it should be read as:

... there were no complications directly related to [the technique including pneumothorax] or [the use of local anesthetics].

How you change it depends on whether pneumothorax applies only to "the technique" or to both. For example:

If you can improve it with the following you don't need to add "directly related to":

> .....there were no complications, **such as pneumothorax**, directly related to the technique or the use of local anesthetics.

But if this is the intent, then I agree you need to add it:

> ...there were no complications directly related to the technique, **such as** pneumothorax, or **directly related to** the use of local anesthetics.

Comment: Thank you very much.